# UINavigationItem.titleView canBecomeFirstResponder?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationitem, titleview

I have a custom UITextField added to the UINavigationItem.titleView. But it is not becomeFirstResponder. Why so?

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITextField *titleTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(65.0f, 8.0f, 160.0f, 30.0f)];
    titleTextField.text = @"Untitled";
    titleTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    titleTextField.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    titleTextField.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0f];
    //titleTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    titleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    titleTextField.delegate = self;
    titleTextField.tag = 2;
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleTextField;
    [titleTextField becomeFirstResponder]
}
```

Please advice.

Thanks in Advance,
Bharathi.

Comment: Your code seems fine... did you try to write above code in `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: @Maulik Yes.. But it didn't work!

Comment: Do a quick if..statement to see if it can becomeFirstResponder. like if([titleTextField becomeFirstResponder])

Answer (score 1):

Try `[self.navigationItem.titleView becomeFirstResponder];` instead of `[titleTextField becomeFirstResponder];`

Comment: Tried this too.. But no luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

You also need to conform the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol. I think you do not have conform the protocol.

in .h file (for example)

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

@end
```

Comment: Yes.. Have already done that also.. Conformed UITextFieldDelegate in my .h file                                                            `@interface ShowListViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>{                       //code                                                                  }                                                                  @end`                                                                          But still it didn't work..

Comment: Great.. Can you share your source code here? I might be doing something wrong somewhere then..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[titleTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

then:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleTextField;
```

tell me if any luck...

Comment: Seems like, navigationItem.titleView will not be added to the view hierarchy.. So it won't respond to UIResponderClass... Do correct me If I am wrong...